# Vue.js blank page on server but on localhost it's fine

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a problem with blank screen on server.
I have this inside `main.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios/dist/axios';

import Login from './components/Login.vue';
import Register from './components/Register.vue';
import MainMenu from './components/MainMenu.vue';
import LevelsMenu from './components/LevelsMenu.vue';


Vue.component('app-login', Login);
Vue.component('app-register', Register);
Vue.component('app-main-menu', MainMenu);
Vue.component('app-levels-menu', LevelsMenu);

const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    loggedIn: false,
},
methods: {
    onLogin() {
        var self = this;
        axios.get('/api/user/isLoggedIn').then(function(response) {
            var isLoggedIn = response.data.data;
            self.loggedIn = isLoggedIn;
        });    
    }
},
mounted() {
    var self = this;
    axios.get('/api/user/isLoggedIn').then(function(response) {
        var isLoggedIn = response.data.data;
        self.loggedIn = isLoggedIn;
    });
}
});
```

When the page loads in microsecond I can see there is a content, but after that it dissapears. You can check this happening on http://3dominator.com/demo

I am drawing some components on a screen. Main problem is that on localhost everything looks fine, but on a server it's simply blank.

Any Ideas what could be the issue?

**EDIT**

It doesn't work only on Chrome. On Firefox it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I had to do this:

```
mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
        var self = this;
        axios.get('/api/user/isLoggedIn').then(function(response) {
            var isLoggedIn = response.data.data;
            self.loggedIn = isLoggedIn;
        });
    });
}
```